# How to use Windows Key in my Application

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Like:

```
 Windows Key + E 
Opens a new Explorer Window
```

And:

```
 Windows Key + R 
Displays the Run command
```

How can I use the Windows Key in a KeyDown event of my Application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to process these keys in your event handlers, use Keys.LWin and Keys.RWin

Generally I would not recommend using these, because future versions of Windows can introduce new shortcuts that will interfere with your combinations.

Comment: so let MS own a key... just say no! btw; aren't they called 'Apple Keys'? ;)