# How to use windows key in a WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, sendkeys

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325636/how-to-use-windows-key-in-my-application), I tried to use windows key inside my WPF application. But, it didn't work! Here is my code

```
case "My Computer":
DeviceSpeak.Speak("Opening My Computer");
SendKeys.SendWait("{Key.LWin}E");
break;
```

My question is how to use windows key in C#. I want to open my computer(WindwosKey+E).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to simulate `WIN` key press using `SendKeys`. Anyway, you can open special locations using their CLSIDs:

```
// open "My Computer"
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("::{20d04fe0-3aea-1069-a2d8-08002b30309d}");
```

Some more CLSIDs (some might not work):

```
Administrative Tools: {D20EA4E1-3957-11d2-A40B-0C5020524153}
All Tasks:            {ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}
Control Panel:        {21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002b30309d}
Connections:          {241D7C96-F8BF-4F85-B01F-E2B043341A4B}
Fonts:                {D20EA4E1-3957-11d2-A40B-0C5020524152}
Computer:             {20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}
Documents:            {450D8FBA-AD25-11D0-98A8-0800361B1103}
History:              {ff393560-c2a7-11cf-bff4-444553540000}
Network Places:       {208d2c60-3aea-1069-a2d7-08002b30309d}
Printers and Faxes:   {2227A280-3AEA-1069-A2DE-08002B30309D}
Programs Folder:      {7be9d83c-a729-4d97-b5a7-1b7313c39e0a}
Recycle Bin:          {645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}
Start Menu:           {48e7caab-b918-4e58-a94d-505519c795dc}
Scheduled Tasks:      {D6277990-4C6A-11CF-8D87-00AA0060F5BF}
```

Comment: Would you please describe what actually this thing is ("::{20d04fe0-3aea-1069-a2d8-08002b30309d}")

Comment: In Windows special locations have GUIDs associated with them. They can be used almost like file names if you prefix them with "::". By default `explorer.exe` is assigned to handle these locations, so when you specify a GUID with "::" prefix, explorer is launched and GUID is passed to it as a command line argument. Explorer then opens related special location. These GUID values are hard-coded, you can find them on MSDN, or using registry editor.

Comment: These values are same across computers and even Windows versions. Once assigned by Microsoft, they stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can find more information about CLSID [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/CLSID-List.htm) and a hope quick Google search will help you a lot.